# django-filter how to add attribute to html tag under form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-filter

I'm using Django-filter,I tried to add attributes by using widget and attrs:

filter.py:

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    messageText = django_filters.CharFilter(widget=(attrs={'style':'width: 20px', 'class':'form-select form-select-sm'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ['messageText ']
```

Then I got:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax at here 'attrs={'
```

Any friend can help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `widget` for a `CharFilter` is a [**`TextInput`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput):

```
from django.forms import TextInput


class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    messageText = django_filters.CharFilter(
        widget=TextInput(
            attrs={'style': 'width: 20px', 'class': 'form-select form-select-sm'}
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ['messageText']
```